# Resizing an UITableViewCell using AutoLayout on iOS 7 and iOS 8

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, autolayout, ios8

I want to resize a UITableViewCell when it is selected. In iOS 7 I designed two table view cells of different heights and replaced the one with the other when selected:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // ...

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    // ...

}
```

I set the height correspondingly:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow isEqual:indexPath]) {
        return 163.0f;
    }
    else {
        return 60.0f;
    }
}
```

**Problem:**
When selecting the row on iOS 8 it will load the new cell but it won't change the height of the cell. Instead it will break one of my constraints, enforcing the systems `"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9fdb72b1f0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f9fdb7009f0(60.6667)]>"` constraint.

My first solution was to use `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` instead of `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` but this doesn't work on iOS 7.

Implementing both methods will not produced the desired result on either OS.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I have the same issue.

Comment: No, I ended up inserting additional cells because I wanted to display tabular data anyway. The resulting code however is not trivial, particularly if you want to hide cells and show new cells at the same time. You will need to get your index paths right to prevent hiccups when reloading the data.

Comment: I recommend posting your work around or deleting the question.